# How do I assign argument properties to self?

Tags: javascript, node.js

### Aim

I am aiming to emulate the [Mongoose](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose) model "class" using an in-memory store. Here is an example of what that might look like:

```
var Book = require("./book");
var book = new Book({
  title: "Hello"
});
```

Now, when I pass `book` to, for example, `console.log` the following output is returned:

```
console.log(book); // returns { title: "Hello" }
```

### Problem

I made a function called `MyBook` that emulates the Mongoose model "class":

```
function MyBook(doc) {
  this.doc = doc;
}
var book = new MyBook({title: "Hello"});
```

But when I pass `book` to `console.log`, the output is different:

```
console.log(book); // returns { doc: { title: "Hello" } }
```

This makes sense to me. I am assigning to `doc` so it makes sense that I have a property `doc`. This is not what I want, though. What I want is an output like the one Mongoose returns. I assign to `doc` because, when I assign to `this`:

```
function MyBook(doc) {
  this = doc;
}
```

I get this error:

```
ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
```

Again, this makes sense to me. But the question remains: **How do I (dynamically) assign properties of the given argument to the current object?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can iterate over all the properties of `doc` with a `for...in` loop:

```
function MyBook(doc) {
  for (var property in doc) {
    if (doc.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
      this[property] = doc[property];
    }
  }
}

var book = new MyBook({title: "Hello"});
```

Soon you'll be able to just do [`Object.assign(this, doc)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `extend` function from `util` module to merge the passed arguments with the self `this` object

```
var extend = require('util')._extend
;

var MyBook = function(options) {
    extend(this, options);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use JavaScripts arguments object. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

```
function MyBook() {
    this.title = arguments[0];
    this.other = arguments[1]
}
var book = new MyBook("Hello", "Other");
console.log(book); // returns - MyBook {title: "Hello", other: "Other"}
```

Though doing it this way you need to set up the properties you want on MyBook originally. This doesnt really match the "dynamic" element you were looking for but does match your aim, the idea of a "class"